# why this jquery function don't work in IE6/7?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

the code is this, is a simple div horizontal scroller:

```
var c = 0;
$("#sezDati_imp_avanti").click(function (event) {
    avantiImp();
    event.preventDefault();
});

function avantiImp() {
    if (c == 0) {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "-165px"
        }, 500);
        c = 1;
    } else {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "-" + (165 * c) + "px"
        }, 500);
        c++;
    }
}

$("#sezDati_imp_indietro").click(function (event) {
    //$('#sezDati_scroller').animate({ marginLeft: "165px"}, 500 );
    indietroImp();
    event.preventDefault();
});

function indietroImp() {
    if (c == 0 || c == 1) {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 500);

    } else {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "-" + (165 * (c - 2)) + "px"
        }, 500);
        c--;
    }
}
```

helppp! :-)

Comment: Why would you *not* indent your code? It's a total time waste not to, and makes it frustrating for everyone else to read...and make them far less likely to help you.

Comment: What is not working? Is there any error?

Comment: No, no error!.... when i click on div id=sezDati_imp_avanti nothing happen...

Answer (score 1):

Under Internet Explorer, [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a member of the [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535873%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object. Since `window` is the default object, maybe there's a conflict with your parameter name. Try using another name, such as `e`:

```
$("#sezDati_imp_indietro").click(function(e) {
    //$('#sezDati_scroller').animate({ marginLeft: "165px"}, 500 );
    indietroImp();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var c = 0;

function avantiImp() {
    if (c == 0) {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "-165px"
        }, 500);
        c = 1;
    } else {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "-" + (165 * c) + "px"
        }, 500);
        c++;
    }
}

function indietroImp() {
    if (c == 0 || c == 1) {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "0px"
        }, 500);

    } else {
        $('#sezDati_scroller').animate({
            marginLeft: "-" + (165 * (c - 2)) + "px"
        }, 500);
        c--;
    }
}

$(function() {

  $("#sezDati_imp_avanti").click(function (ev) {
      avantiImp();
      ev.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#sezDati_imp_indietro").click(function (ev) {
      //$('#sezDati_scroller').animate({ marginLeft: "165px"}, 500 );
      indietroImp();
      ev.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

Comment: Ok, I have add an alert(c); into the two function and alert work...So i think there is something wrong in the jquery animation...